# how to extract byte data from bluetooth heart rate monitor in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, bluetooth-lowenergy, uint8t

Im having trouble understanding bytes and uint8_t values.

I am using the sample project created by apple that reads data from a Bluetooth 4.0 heart rate monitor via the heart rate service protocol. THe sample project gives out heart rate data as below:

```
- (void) updateWithHRMData:(NSData *)data 
{
const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];
uint16_t bpm = 0;

if ((reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0) 
{
    /* uint8 bpm */
    bpm = reportData[1];
} 
else 
{
    /* uint16 bpm */
    bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[1]));
}
```

I am assuming that (reportData[0] & 0x01) returns the first data bit in the data array reportData but I dont know how to access the second, (reportData[0] & 0x02) doesn't work like I thought it would.
Ideally I would like to check all the data in reportData[0] and then based on that grab the rr interval data in reportData[4] or [5] dependant on where it is stored and iterate through it to get each value as I believe there can be multiple values stored there.

a newbie question I know but Im having trouble finding the answer, or indeed the search terms to establish the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `reportData[0]` you are getting the first byte (at index 0). When you combine that value with `reportData[0] & 0x02`, you are masking out all but the 2nd bit. This result will either be 0 (if bit 2 is not set) or it will be 2 (if the 2nd bit is set).

```
if ((reportData[0] & 0x02) == 0) {
    // bit 2 of first byte is not set
} else {
    // bit 2 of first byte is set
}
```

If you want to check all 8 bits then you could do:

```
uint8_t byte = reportData[0];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    int mask = 1 << i;
    if ((byte & mask) == 0) {
        bit i is not set
    } else {
        bit i is set
    }
}
```

Update: To extract a value that spans two bits you do something like this:

```
uint8_t mask = 0x01 | 0x02; // Good for value stored in the first two bits
uint8_t value = byte & mask; // value now has just value from first two bits
```

If the value to extract is in higher bits then there is an extra step:

```
uint8_t mask = 0x02 | 0x04; // Good for value in 2nd and 3rd bits
uint8_t value = (byte & mask) >> 1; // need to shift value to convert to regular integer
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I was wondering though, what if a value is spread over 2 bits, e.g. the bits store either the numbers 1,2,3 or 4? I assume that to store either 3 or 4, 2 bits need to be used, but how does one look at those two bits "as a whole" and then extract a single number from them and store in an int for example?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038906/apples-heart-rate-monitoring-example-and-byte-order-of-bluetooth-heart-rate-mea) for a discussion of the sample code.  The post also links to the [Bluetooth spec](http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml) which should help you understand why the endianess check is being performed (basically it's Apple ensuring maximum portability).  Basically, the first byte is a bit field describing the format of the HRV data and the presence/absence of EE and RR interval data.  So:

```
reportData[0] & 0x03
```

tells you if EE data are present (1 = yes, 0 = no), and

```
reportData[0] & 0x04
```

tells you if RR interval data are present (1 = yes, 0 = no)

You can then get RR interval data with

```
uint16_t rrinterval;
rrinterval = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[idx]));
```

where `idx` is determined by the presence/absence tests you performed.  I am assuming that the offsets are not fixed BTW as that's what you are indicating (i.e., dynamic offsets based on presence/absence) -- I'm not familiar with the BT spec.  If the format *is* fixed, in this case the RR data would be at offset 7.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the original question has not been answered yet. Rory also wants to know how to parse all the RR-interval data, as there can be multiple values within in one message (I have seen up to three). The RR-interval data is not always located within the same bytes. It depends on several things:

- is the BPM written into a single byte or two?
- is there EE data present?
- calculate the number of RR-interval values

Here is the actual spec of the [Heart_rate_measurement characteristic](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml)

```
// Instance method to get the heart rate BPM information
- (void) getHeartBPMData:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
    // Get the BPM //
    // https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml //

    // Convert the contents of the characteristic value to a data-object //
    NSData *data = [characteristic value];

    // Get the byte sequence of the data-object //
    const uint8_t *reportData = [data bytes];

    // Initialise the offset variable //
    NSUInteger offset = 1;
    // Initialise the bpm variable //
    uint16_t bpm = 0;


    // Next, obtain the first byte at index 0 in the array as defined by reportData[0] and mask out all but the 1st bit //
    // The result returned will either be 0, which means that the 2nd bit is not set, or 1 if it is set //
    // If the 2nd bit is not set, retrieve the BPM value at the second byte location at index 1 in the array //
    if ((reportData[0] & 0x01) == 0) {
        // Retrieve the BPM value for the Heart Rate Monitor
        bpm = reportData[1];

        offset = offset + 1; // Plus 1 byte //
    }
    else {
        // If the second bit is set, retrieve the BPM value at second byte location at index 1 in the array and //
        // convert this to a 16-bit value based on the host’s native byte order //
        bpm = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[1]));

        offset =  offset + 2; // Plus 2 bytes //
    }
    NSLog(@"bpm: %i", bpm);



    // Determine if EE data is present //
    // If the 3rd bit of the first byte is 1 this means there is EE data //
    // If so, increase offset with 2 bytes //
    if ((reportData[0] & 0x03) == 1) {
        offset =  offset + 2; // Plus 2 bytes //
    }



    // Determine if RR-interval data is present //
    // If the 4th bit of the first byte is 1 this means there is RR data //
    if ((reportData[0] & 0x04) == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", @"Data are not present");
    }
    else
    {
        // The number of RR-interval values is total bytes left / 2 (size of uint16) //

        NSUInteger length = [data length];
        NSUInteger count = (length - offset)/2;
        NSLog(@"RR count: %lu", (unsigned long)count);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            // The unit for RR interval is 1/1024 seconds //
            uint16_t value = CFSwapInt16LittleToHost(*(uint16_t *)(&reportData[offset]));
            value = ((double)value / 1024.0 ) * 1000.0;

            offset = offset + 2; // Plus 2 bytes //

            NSLog(@"RR value %lu: %u", (unsigned long)i, value);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The code you posted seems to be incorrect. According to the spec bit index 3 tells you if EE is present meaning your check would be (since we start counting at 0) `reportData[0] & pow(2,2)` or just `0x04` and for RR(bit index 4) your mask would be `0x08` or `pow(2,3)`.