# How do I publish multiple pieces of BLE characteristic data using bleno

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bleno

I'm trying to learn how to implement a BLE peripheral device using [bleno](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno).  I would like to discover and read from the peripheral using [noble](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble).  For example sake, I want to know how I would implement a simple smart scale that reports back weight, BMI etc following the [Weight Measurement GATT spec](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_measurement.xml).

What I can't figure out is if reading multiple pieces of information from a characteristic is possible.  The [Weight Measurement GATT spec](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_measurement.xml) makes it seem like in a single noble `characteristic.read()` you can simultaneously retrieve Weight, BMI, Height etc.

For example, this simple bleno characteristic:

```
'use strict';

const bleno = require('bleno');

const flags = {
  IMPERIAL_WEIGHT: 1 << 0,
  USER_ID_PRESENT: 1 << 2,
  BMI_AND_HEIGHT_PRESENT: 1 << 3
};

module.exports.flags = flags;

module.exports.WeightMeasureCharacteristic = class WeightMeasureCharacteristic extends bleno.Characteristic {
  constructor(scale) {
    super({
      uuid: '2A9D',
      properties: ['read'],
      descriptors: []
    });
    this._scale = scale;
  }

  onReadRequest(offset, callback) {
    //Not sure what `offset` means here or how it gets populated...Help!

    let data = new Buffer.alloc(8); //1(flags)+2(weightImp)+1(userId)+2(BMI)+2(heightImp)

    //Write supported value fields as bit flags
    data.writeUInt8(flags.IMPERIAL_WEIGHT | flags.USER_ID_PRESENT | flags.BMI_AND_HEIGHT_PRESENT), 0);

    //Write out weight (lbs) - offset 1 byte
    data.writeUInt16LE(100.01, 1);

    //Write out user id - offset 12 bytes (flags+Imperial, no need to include offset for SI or Timestamp since the flags indicated those are not supported)
    data.writeUInt8(69, 3);

    //Write out BMI - offset 13 bytes (after UserId)
    data.writeUInt16LE(18.6, 4);

    //Write out Height Imperial - offset 17 bytes (after Height SI)
    data.writeUInt16LE(72.2, 6);

    callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, data);
  }
}
```

If someone was able to implement/pseudocode `onReadRequest()` above I think it would help things click in my head.

Questions:

1. Does the `C<number>` value in the "Field Requirement" column of the [spec](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.weight_measurement.xml) indicate the `offset` value passed into `onReadRequest()`?  If a consumer wanted to get "Weight - SI"(`C1`) they would somehow construct a noble `characteristic.read()` that triggers an `onReadRequest(1,function())`?  If so, how is the `characteristic.read()` constructed?
2. How do I construct a noble `characteristic.read()` to get the value of the `Flags`?
3. How do I construct a noble `characteristic.read()` that will return me multiple (or all) properties in one read? Ex: Give me all values this peripheral supports (Weight - SI, BMI etc).
4. If my peripheral supports imperial weight, user id, bmi, and height how do I populate the `data` for the callback in `onReadRequest()`. Is what I have above correct?
5. How is `offset` populated & what does it mean in `onReadRequest(offset,callback)`?

Or, am I doing this all wrong? Should I have a characteristic for each value? Ex: a single characteristic for weight - SI, and another characteristic for BMI?  I would like to avoid this, would prefer to save round trips and get multiple values in one call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attempt to answer your question:

1. I am not sure what the `C<number>` means, but I believe that each field (Weight, BMI, Height, etc.) is represented as a group of one or more octets. Notice how at the bottom of the spec it says

> Note: The fields in the above table are in the order of LSO to MSO.
>   Where LSO = Least Significant Octet and MSO = Most Significant Octet.

Thus, I believe that in order to get the "Weight - SI" field, you would do something like:

```
    characteristic.read((err, data) => {
      let char_flags = data.readUint8(0); // read first bit
      if (!(char_flags & flags.IMPERIAL_WEIGHT)) // if SI weight
        let weightSI = data.readUint16LE(1) // read SI weight starting at second bit
    });
```

2. Answered above
3. Answered above, just check whether the property exists in the flags and then read the value from the appropriate offset. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038906/apples-heart-rate-monitoring-example-and-byte-order-of-bluetooth-heart-rate-mea) might help.
4. Answered above.

Comment: thx for the quick response.  This helps with initiating the read of the characteristic, but I'm still confused how the `offset` param in `onReadRequest` works (added a 5th q).  From your answers I took a stab at implementation of `onReadRequest` (and re-worded q #4).  Does this look correct? Specifically my logic to allocate buffer, and how to add values at an offset?

Comment: Offset is used for reading of "long" characteristics (> 20 bytes). If the characteristic is greater than the MTU (maximum transmission unit), the host will have to call read several times, each time with a different offset. I am just extrapolating from this answer [here](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/bleno/issues/104#issuecomment-96411894). Your implementation looks correct to me, except that you should not need to include the lengths of SI or timestamp into your byte offset calculations since your flags are indicating these as not present. Thus user id would be data.writeUInt8(69, 3)

Comment: Thank you my friend.  There is no way to define an offset when the consumer of the device is doing a `characteristic.read((err, data) => {...`.  Therefore are you staying that logic built into the consumer code will do multiple reads (passing an offset) if required?  "I don't know" is cool with me, it is not blocking me from setting this answer as correct, just helps it be complete in my head.

Comment: I am not sure, as I have not used this feature, but I believe this to be the case from what I've read